# What it does mean "bender"? word taken from the cartoon Avatar - the last Airbender

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

In this cartoon Airbender is man who have magic force - magic of air.

In dictionary this word is "a period during which a large amount of alcohol is drunk" and "a person or thing that bends, as a pair of pliers or a powered machine".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bender is a person or thing that bends something else. To bend something is to change its shape or direction without breaking it. The element benders are shaping and turning the elements to their will.

Comment: Note that we also have the phrase "to bend reality to one's will", which means "to change reality such that it's as one wishes". "Bender" in "Airbender" as a similar meaning, basically changing something.

Comment: Other related ideas: pipe-bender, mind-bending

Comment: The ideas @JustinStafford wrote are like separated in two words (pipe, bender). Why is Airbender one word? It is correct to say something like 'Timebender' (Meaning 'A master of time') ?